# Blender has stopped working

Tags: blender, blender-2.76

I can not get Blender working, it crashes on startup.

I tried to un-install and re-install again, it does not work.

error images:

[Error Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Laa.png)

[Error Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrOJ2.png)

please help me.

Comment: It looks to be trying to load a file within `c:\Tribon`, does that exist? is it something you have uninstalled recently? It could be an addon you have installed, try starting blender from the cmd prompt with the `--factory-startup` option or move your [config files](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) to clear any settings and installed addons. Another option is after you uninstall blender check that there is no blender folder left inside Program Files and then re-install.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. Tribon is another application i have installed last year, but thanks for this note, i will try to remove it and re-install Blender

Comment: this solved my problem, i jyst removed this file related to Tribon, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

solution was by moving this file to another folder. (see image attached)

[click to see error image screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jFKJ.png)

thank you @sambler